# Jenkins job build history lost after migrating workspace to a new hard drive

Tags: jenkins

I am currently running Jenkins ver. 2.121.2. I am in charge to migrate all jenkins builds and workspace to a new location since we have many projects filling our system's SSD. And we decided to have the workspace and build location to be on a HDD. Migrating all the data wasn't hard but the unexpected side effect is, that all jenkins jobs have lost their build history. I thought it would be as simple as copying all files over to the new location.

I changed only 2 parameters in the `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` file. These are from:

`<workspaceDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace</workspaceDir>
<buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>`

To...

`<workspaceDir>/wd-red1/jenkins_workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}</workspaceDir>
<buildsDir>/wd-red1/jenkins_builds/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</buildsDir>`

Then I have copied all files from `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace` and `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs` respectively to the locations above. All went well except for the job build histories.

My question is: Can I somehow import the job build history too?

Comment: Did all sub folders under /var/lib/jenkins/jobs get copied over correctly ?

Comment: Yeah, I checked that. I used `cp -r * /wd-red1/jenkins_builds/` to copy those over.

Answer (score 0):

If your old jenkins instance is still running, install "thinbackup" and take a full backup. Copying the backup into the new server and restoring the backup will give you all the configurations as it is in old server. I tried this someday back and it worked liked a charm.

Note :  Thinbackup plug in supports both backup and restore.

Comment: That did not work. All build history is still lost. I have reverted the setting in `config.xml` to get all the build history, then I backed everything up (waited for some time until I saw the backup location stopped growing in size), then I shut down jenkins, changed the workspace+build location, started jenkins up and restored the backup. Everything is still the same :/
I would need the build history files themselves.

Comment: I believe you wouldn't have checked "Backup build results"  in thin backup setting. To be on the safer side, click all the checkbox in thinbackup settings and take a backup

Comment: I did that too, however some checkboxes according to their labels wouldn't backup what may be the build history and as such I did not select those. These are "Backup only builds marked to keep", "Backup additional files", "Move old backups to ZIP files" and others like that.